# Constantly look for file, when file exist, run command

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, vbscript

```
FileName = "C:\Users\amrapab\Desktop\Test\remedy\Auto\Open dump 23 Mar.csv"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Do
   If FSO.FileExists(FileName) Then 

       CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Users\amrapab\Desktop\Test\remedy\Auto\test.vbs"
FSO.DeleteFile FileName
   End If
   WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: before triger test.vbs exists file deleted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: when i use above .vbs file to run infinity ,  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Users\amrapab\Desktop\Test\remedy\Auto\test.vbs" was not work and existing file Open dump 23 Mar.csv was delete

Comment: Add some delay for your vbs script to do it's work before you delete the file you are trying to work on. I.E. before you FSO.DeleteFile add in Wscript.Sleep XXXX.